# django rest framework update nested serializer by id

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to update a list in a nested serializer by id

I have a user who has multiple contacts

Example:

contact serializer

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'last_name'
        ]
```

user serializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[
            UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())
        ]
    )
    contacts = ContactSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "email",
            "contacts"
        ]


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        contacts_data = validated_data.pop('contacts')
        contacts = (instance.contacts).all()
        contacts = list(contacts)
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.save()

        # many contacts
        for contact_data in contacts_data:
            contact = contacts.pop(0)
            contact.name = contact_data.get('name', contact.name)
            contact.last_name = contact_data.get('last_name', contact.last_name)
            contact.save()

        return instance
```

I want to update contacts by ID, for now it works, but it only updates the first contact in the list

Example I want to update the contact with ID 4 and 6

Payload request

```
{
    "name": "string",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "id": 4, 
            "name": "string",
            "last_name": "string"
        },
        {
            "id": 6, 
            "name": "string",
            "last_name": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: how are you sending the contacts ? what's in your request ? show an example of the data you are sending to the serializer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it like this

```py
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        contacts_data = validated_data.pop('contacts')

        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.save()

        # many contacts
        for contact_data in contacts_data:
            contact = Contact.objects.get(pk=contact_data['id']) # this will crash if the id is invalid though
            contact.name = contact_data.get('name', contact.name)
            contact.last_name = contact_data.get('last_name', contact.last_name)
            contact.save()

        return instance
```

Comment: Works, thanks, a little change, contact_data it's a OrderedDict: contact_data['id']

Comment: Don't save it inside for loop. Save them once outside of the for loop.

Comment: @mcan that doesn't make sense, it's updating separate records, would need to save each one

Comment: @Jimmar You should use sth. like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661253/how-to-bulk-update-with-django#answer-70765317

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same problem with the above mentioned solution:
DRF seems to remove the "id" field from validated_data if this field is not a writable field. Setting it writable does not make sense in my eyes as we only want it to get the correct objects.

**EDIT:** the proper way to do this, is probably to add the id field to the `ContactSerializer` as follows (credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37275096):

```
id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
```

---

**OLD:**
Here is my workaround, tho I am happy to read the proper way to do this:

Overwrite the `to_internal_value` of your `ContactSerializer` as follows:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    id_field = data.get("id", None)
    ret = super().to_internal_value(data)
    ret["id"] = id_field
    return ret
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34524563)