Updating a Foreign Key in Django Rest Framework
these are my models in DRF:
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Prerequisite(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE,           related_name="course_prerequisite")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)

and my serializers:
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prerequisite = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    class Meta:
        model = models.Course
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_prerequisite(self, obj):
        serializer = PrerequisiteSerializer(obj.course_prerequisite.all(), many=True)
        return serializer.data

class PrerequisiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Prerequisite
        fields = "__all__"

and my view to retrieve a course:
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        course = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=pk)
        serializer = serializers.CourseSerializer(instance=course)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

now my question is imagine i did send a request to my api to retrieve a course with pk of 18 like this:
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 18,
            'title': 'learn python in 30 days'
            "prerequisite": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "Introduction",
                    "course": 18
                },
            ],
        }
    ]
}

and now i want update the prerequisite with id of 1 what code should i add to my update view in CourseViewSet, i know i can create another view for prerequisites, but i want to do it in this way exactly like when you add TabularInLine in Django`s default admin panel when you can update and change a foreignkey!

Have you checked out NestedSerializers? These allow you to skip the MethodField pattern.
The docs are here.
They also include some code for creating relations through NestedSerializers. Updating relationships have the same pattern. Let me know if you need any help with that.

This question can also provide you with some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443223/django-rest-framework-update-nested-serializer-by-id

Does this answer your question? django rest framework update nested serializer by id
